# React useEffect hook is not behaving correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am trying to update my child component based on parent state and similarly I am trying to update the parent state by clicking on a button in child component. Both is fine but while clicking on a button in child it's updating the parent but instead of the only clicked child iits opening both the child how to solve the issue using react hook? I want to open only one child while clicking child but the Expand all button of parent should change to collapse all.

I am adding my codesandbox for better understanding

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-parent-child-functional-component-example-forked-xkpvsl?file=/src/Child.js

Parent to child update and child to parent by a event handler is happening but while clicking child i want to update the state of parent but not to open both the child only clicked child?

Comment: if I understand correctly your question, its happening because you are using only 1 state to control both the buttons states. Use two separate states for each button.

Comment: Yes I am using one state to render both the buttons states. It could be 2 could be 10 20 buttons also.

Comment: What's your requirement? When you click the first button, it should not trigger the second button?

Comment: You're using one state for both buttons. How do you expect it to NOT trigger the other when you trigger one?

Comment: Yes it should not trigger the 2nd but it should update the expand all string in parent to collapse all string

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a [mcve] ***in the post*** so readers can see what the code you are using is doing.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-parent-child-functional-component-example-forked-xkpvsl?file=/src/Child.js I am able to solve it. please take a look and let me know the feedback

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you put 2 child button inside an Child component and you pass the  same open state to both of them.

The solution is split 2 button into 2 Child component.

There is your code

```
<div>
  <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    {button()}
    {open ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>1st button</p> : null}
  </div>
  <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    {button()}
    {open ? <p style={{ color: "green" }}>2nd button</p> : null}
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to change into

```
<div>
  <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    {button()}
    {open ? <p style={{ color: props.color }}>{props.buttonName}</p> : null}
  </div>
</div>
```

So you can pass the buttonName and color props to each child to custom them. And remove handleCollapse()
from button() click event to prevent toggle both children.

About parent node.

Change isExpanded state to array to hold more child state. With this isExpanded state you can check did thay all expanded with every method.

```
const Parent = () => {
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState([false, false, false, false]);
let handleCollapse = () => {
  if (isExpanded.every((ie) => ie === true))
    setIsExpanded(new Array(4).fill(false));
  else setIsExpanded(new Array(4).fill(true));
};
return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => handleCollapse(false)}>
      {isExpanded.every((ie) => ie === true) ? "Collapse All" : "Expand all"}
    </button>
    <Child
      buttonName="1st button"
      color="red"
      isExpanded={isExpanded[0]}
      setIsExpanded={setIsExpanded}
      id={0}
    />
    <Child
      buttonName="2nd button"
      color="green"
      isExpanded={isExpanded[1]}
      setIsExpanded={setIsExpanded}
      id={1}
    />
    <Child
      buttonName="3rd button"
      color="blue"
      isExpanded={isExpanded[2]}
      setIsExpanded={setIsExpanded}
      id={2}
    />
    <Child
      buttonName="4th button"
      color="yellow"
      isExpanded={isExpanded[3]}
      setIsExpanded={setIsExpanded}
      id={3}
    />
);
```

};

Comment: about collapse all / expand all button. you can create some logic to detect that children is all collapsed or expanded to change the button text correctly

Comment: Yes this what I am looking how can I track from parent component?

Comment: i prefer to change isExpanded in to an array with length equal to children. The isExpanded value is bool ([true, false]). <Children isExpaned={isExpanded[0]} /> and you can detect with every method (when every child expand => change button to collapse all and reverse)

Comment: Hey, I have updated my code https://codesandbox.io/s/react-parent-child-functional-component-example-forked-xkpvsl?file=/src/Parent.js in the same sandbox now if u see after one single button click its opening one and changing expand all to collapse all but after that if anyone click on collapse all its not collapsing its collapsing after 2nd click, is there any solution for that?

Comment: Your update is not same with my idea. So i did i. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-parent-child-functional-component-example-forked-cv874f?file=/src/Parent.js

Comment: Hi saw your code but now if I click individual button then expand all is not changing to collapse all which is the main feature I am looking

Comment: You can add 1 more button (expand all) in case 1 or more button expanded. Or change the collapse all button to expand all

Comment: Base on my code I think you should did it yourself

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-parent-child-functional-component-example-forked-xkpvsl?file=/src/Child.js Hey i am able to solve it take a look at my solution once and give your feedback

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-parent-child-functional-component-example-forked-xkpvsl?file=/src/Child.js

can look into my codesandbox which has complete solution.

The main challenge was to manipulate the parent state from child for that i am using a eventHandler from child to notify if any button is open or not or all the buttons are closed / opened. Based on the state i am changing the button text from Expand All to Collapse All and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a additional state in Parent.js a long with State handler.

```
const [expandCount, setExpandCount] = useState(0);

const expandCountHandler = (action) => {
   if (action === "opened") {
      setExpandCount(expandCount + 1);
   } else {
      setExpandCount(expandCount - 1);
   }
};
```

Pass the handler in the Child component.

```
<Child
    buttonName="1st button"
    handleCollapse={handleCollapse}
    color="red"
    isExpanded={isExpanded}
    expandCountHandler={expandCountHandler}
/>
```

Call the handler from the Child.js

```
onClick={() => {
   setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
   props.expandCountHandler(open ? "closed" : "opened");
}}
```

In the Parent button, you need to handle onclick event based on the `expandCount` state.

Give that a try.

Comment: Please check my codesandbox once. Parent component don't have multiple child it has one child but in child i have multiple elements that is expanding and collapsing based on parent state and vice versa from child elements

Comment: @AbhishekPaul try the updated answer. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Hey, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-parent-child-functional-component-example-forked-xkpvsl?file=/src/Parent.js just check once its not working. after individual click its opening only one and changing the expand all to Collapse all but if we click collapse all its opening all instead of collapsing the open one

Comment: Hey, I did further update now expand all collapse all is ok warning. If i individually change it then it's changing expand all to collapse all . everything is fine only issue left is now after individual child open if i click collapse all its first opening all and then again if click its closing all.

Comment: @AbhishekPaul looks like you are almost there. Keep debugging the onclick handler of Parent component. For example If you click collapse all, make the `expandCount` to 0 and when click expand all, set the value to 2 (if you have 2 child component) so on.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-parent-child-functional-component-example-forked-xkpvsl?file=/src/Child.js Please take a look at my solution. i am able to solve all the issues.